# No warning from jquery Migrate plug-in when using removeProp() incorrectly

Tags: jquery, jquery-migrate

Before I explain the issue let me tell you I am clearly aware that jQuery removeProp should not be used on native properties such as disabled, checked and selected. https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/

We upgraded the jQuery from 1.12.3 to 3.6.0. We used the JQuery migrate plug-in to identify compatibility issues and fix all the warnings generated in console.

`$(“#x”).removeProp(“disabled”)` did work in 1.12.3 and stopped working after upgrading to latest version. But we were not able to identify the issue unless we tested the pages manually. I want to know why jQuery migrate plug-in did not give us a warning regarding the same.

I know we used it wrongly before and we are happy to correct it to `$(“#x”).prop(“disabled”,false)`

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: I already know the fix I have to do using .prop() method. My concern is on the migrate plugin not giving warnings.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the development version of jQuery-Migrate? You don't get warnings about using obsolete interfaces if you use the production version.

Comment: @Barmar yes I am using the development version, I was able to verify and fix other warnings logged in the console.

Comment: There's nothing in the documentation that says this changed between versions.

Comment: It looks like it's still supposed to remove the property. The documentation still says "This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element." If it's not working in jQuery 3.x, that seems like it was not intended.

Comment: @Barmar Even I was confused with the statement. If it would have removed the property completely it would still be desired use case in our code. Apparently, It stopped working from 2.x.

Comment: I just looked at the implementations in 1.x and 3.x. The difference is that 1.x did `this[name] = undefined`, while 3.x does `delete this[name]`. I think the latter is supposed to implement "remove the property completely", but maybe it's implementation-dependent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232319/discussion-between-akshay-gaonkar-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an explanation, by Timmy Willison from jQuery Core Team in this bug report https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/4887

> I think this is just a docs issue. We should change that to say "This
> can remove the property completely or have no effect at all." I
> followed the code and it's just calling delete, which is the right
> thing. 1.x used to set properties to undefined for old IE, which is no
> longer necessary and technically invalid.
>
> That said, this is somewhat moot. The reason needs updating, but the
> recommendation remains valid. There's no reason you should need to
> remove a native property (nor should you expect that to work–Blink is
> making it impossible anyway). It's not the same as removing a content
> attribute, which would actually set the corresponding property to
> false. Setting to false is the right thing here.

The issue raised resulted in the change in the documentation of `.removeProp()`. https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/pull/1189